# Wordpress, If PAGE is PAGED

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

In the following case, I need to add  to pages that have been paged.

I've come up with the following but it really feels as though there is a better way to do it.  Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated:

```
<?php if( is_page() ):?>

    <?php if ($paged) { ?>
       <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php if( is_page() && is_paged() ) { ?>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
<?php } ?>
```

This will do exactly the same except you don't need to worry about setting the value of the $paged variable which you're using above.

Comment: @yYavor , any idea what I need to have done to make is_paged work?  is_paged itself doesn't seem to be a variable

Comment: Can you please post a link to the URL where you're checking this?